# securing an endpoint using sub-domain (cert from godaddy, DNS resolution on AWS Route 53, app hosted on Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, ssl, azure-aks, amazon-route53

We have a static website hosted on AWS for a domain registered with Godaddy. We primarily use route53 for all DNS resolution for static website as well as office 365. We have recently developed a small app hosted on Azure Kubernetes Service. I have updated route53 accordingly on AWS and DNS Zone to use a subdomain xxx.abc.com to point to the AKS private IP. the app is accessible only through HTTP. we have got a wildcard cert to be able to use the cert for all sub domains. I have been exploring and It appears there is no option to use this TLS cert on route 53 as it is only doing DNS resolution.

I am quite new to Azure services. Can someone kindly advise on how to secure this endpoint using the cert.

I tried searching over internet and it seems ingress controller is the only way forward (reference links below). I am trying to see if there is any other way.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls?tabs=azure-cli
https://snyk.io/blog/setting-up-ssl-tls-for-kubernetes-ingress/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Route53 is only a DNS service, doing the address translation, nothing to do with the ssl certificate.

For your need there are several components that need to fit together:

In Kubernetes the *ingress controller* is basically a load balancer routing external traffic to the pods.

On AKS, it is possible and recommended to configure the Application Gateway (the default Azure load balancer) as an ingress controller.

What you may be looking for is [AGIC (Application Gateway Ingress controller)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-install-new). The article concerns about configuring the AGIC itself, not yet ssl (step-by-step)

Then you could search to [configure a SSL cert the AGIC](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/features/appgw-ssl-certificate/), I suggest to store the private key/certificate to the KeyVault

You could manager and configure the ingress controller and certificates directly on kubernetes worker nodes (less dependent on Azure iteself), but then you need to expose the worker nodes on public IP, manage their fixed IP addresses,... or having a separate load balancer server in front of a cluster. Using AGIC is considered much safer